# SQL Query involving selection of highest occuring value for a specific combination

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the value from the value column, which occurs most number of times, and replace that value in that particular material and plant combination. If there is no value which is repeating twice or more than that, I make that as 0.

For example, in the example below, Within A + P1, 20 is occurring the most number of times, so we make all the values of that A+P1 as 20.

IN B+P2, none of the values are repeating, so I make all of them as 0.

[image: Please see the input and output example here]

Comment: Please post images like text. Read this [Article](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) to know why.

Comment: Please provide what SQL you already have along with the scheme for your table and the example data in your description not as an image.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify which version of MySQL.  If it's 5.x, you may benefit from using a correlated subquery to look up the most common value and apply the "at least two occurences" constraint, then use `COALESCE(x, 0)` to force it to be 0 if there is no such value...

```
SELECT
  *,
  COALESCE(
    (
      SELECT lookup.value
        FROM yourTable AS lookup
       WHERE lookup.mat = yourTable.mat
         AND lookup.plant = yourTable.plant
    GROUP BY lookup.value
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, lookup.value DESC
       LIMIT 1
    ),
    0
  )
   AS most_common_value
FROM
  yourTable
```

Note, I've included `lookup.value DESC` so that if multiple values are equally the most common, the one chosen is the highest value.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the most frequent value using:

```
select t.*
from (select mat, plan, value, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by mat, plan order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by mat, plan, value
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

You can incorporate this into an `update`:

```
update t join
       (select t.*
        from (select mat, plan, value, count(*) as cnt,
                     row_number() over (partition by mat, plan order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
              from t
             ) t
        where seqnum = 1
       ) tt
       using (mat, plan)
    set t.value = tt.value;
```

EDIT:

To get the full rows from the original table, I would suggest using `JOIN`:

```
select t.*, coalesce(tt.value, 0) as imputed_value
from t left join
     (select t.*
      from (select mat, plan, value, count(*) as cnt,
                   row_number() over (partition by mat, plan order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
            from t
            group by mat, plan, value
            having count(*) > 1
           ) t
      where seqnum = 1
     ) tt
     on tt.mat = t.mat and tt.plan = t.plan;
```

Comment: What if I want more columns apart from Material and Plant? Putting an order by inside e partition throws an Group By clause error